# Does ngrx/store copy the entire state every time I dispatch an action?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm concerned about performance when dispatching actions via ngrx/store.

I have a store with the following shape.

```
state: {
    profile: {
        name: '',
        wishlist: [],
    },
    availableProducts: [],
    cart: [],
}
```

I have a separate reducer for each part - profile, availableProducts, and cart.

If I add something to my cart via an action/cart-reducer, is the entire rest of the state also recreated (profile, availableProducts)? Or is it referencing the same memory.

I'm concerned because of the possibility of 'availableProducts' being *massive*, and if it's getting recreated every time that could definitely affect performance.

Comment: So, then, separate available product state. Maybe, have a product module that takes care of all of that. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/api.md#feature-module-state-composition

Comment: Available products could be dependent on something in profile. Sorry, I couldn't make a more robust example. But, my question is really just whether or not they get copied or if the references are copied.

Comment: State in ngrx is immutable, so you get a new copy each time.

Comment: From my experience and from what I read ngrx being immutable is a principle that the developer should follow. It isn't enforced. You have to introduce another library like immutable.js. Though ngrx may handle the state composition it is the reducers that create the state. So it is up to your reducers as far as whether they return the same reference or a new one. If your reducer doesn't care about the action then it should return the state it was passed.